How to open a session-protected JSF URL within Java bean
I need to open an a URL as an InputStream from within a Java bean in a Tomcat/JSF website.
The URL is protected and the user is already logged in.
Is there a way to open the protected URL using starting from FacesContext?
I'm using JSF 2.3 and Tomcat 9.0
EDIT:
To clarify, I need to do this: InputStream input = new URL("http://localhost/context/page.jsp").openStream();
But page.jsp is password-protected.  The browser can access it because it manages the logged-in user's credentials (session, etc.), but within my Java bean, it tries to redirect to the login page. I want to use the currently logged-in session to access it.
